# How to copy files by extension from Local Machine to Docker Container?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

Currently, I only can copy the entire folder, as follows:

```
docker cp path/to/folder/ ContainerName:/folder/to/docker/container/
```

I would like to do this:

```
docker cp path/to/folder/*.extension ContainerName:/folder/to/docker/container/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible to do this with `docker cp`.

An alternate way to achieve this is to mount the source directory that contains the files into the container. To do this, you can use the `-v` volume flag as below.

`docker run -v /full/path/on/host:/destination/path/in/container ...`